# Can't do ORDER BY with Summed Value

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

An error occurred with MySQL query below:

```
SELECT Id, (
SUM( poskusi ) *3 + SUM( cas )
) AS totals
FROM igralci
GROUP BY totals
LIMIT 5
```

I want to sum up two columns and then I want to get top 5 result of the result. I wrote this code but it doesn't work at line `GROUP BY` totals. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: "Does not work" means exactly what? Do you get an error, the wrong result, ...? It would also be helpful to show your table definition.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get an error('Can't group on 'totals'). My table definition is:
CREATE TABLE igralci

(

Id int(11), PRIMARY KEY

poskusi int(11),

cas int(11),

);

Comment: Show some input data and the expected outcome.

Comment: Id| poskusi| cas

1| 1     | 32  
2| 2     | 34  
3| 5     | 42  
4| 8     | 29 
.
.
The expected outcome would be for each Id the summed "poskusi" and "cas" column and at the end would get top 5(the lowest 5) sums.

Comment: Are you trying `ORDER BY` (as mentioned in the title) or `GROUP BY` (as mentioned in the question itself)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT Id,(
SUM(poskusi) * 3 + SUM(cas)
) AS totals
FROM igralci
GROUP BY Id
LIMIT 5
```

You cannot use **Alias** in `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: This only bring out the top 5 Id's. not the top 5 sums

Comment: Yes, it brings out the top 5 ID's with their corresponding sums.